# Bash scripting if or

Tags: bash

I am trying to get an if or working in bash and its not work. Getting the following error

```
./install.sh: line 33: conditional binary operator expected
./install.sh: line 33: syntax error near `$CURRENT_OS'
./install.sh: line 33: `elif [[ $CURRENT_OS =~ "CYGWIN" || [ $CURRENT_OS =~ "MSYS" ]]; then'
```

Here is my current script

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT_OS=$(uname)

echo "Installing dotfiles"

echo "Initializing submodule(s)"
#git submodule update --init --recursive

# Used for setting up a mac
if [ $CURRENT_OS == "Darwin" ]; then
    echo "Running OSX"
elif [[ $CURRENT_OS =~ "CYGWIN" || [ $CURRENT_OS =~ "MSYS" ]]; then
    echo $CURRENT_OS
fi
```

I have even tried this

```
elif [ $CURRENT_OS =~ "CYGWIN" || [ $CURRENT_OS =~ "MSYS" ]; then
```

And I get this error

```
./install.sh: line 33: [: missing `]'
./install.sh: line 33: [: =~: binary operator expected
```

Comment: Your `elif` has imbalanced brackets. One more `[` than `]`.Did you try, `elif [ $CURRENT_OS =~ "CYGWIN" || $CURRENT_OS =~ "MSYS" ];`?

Comment: You should try http://shellcheck.net/ before posting here about simple syntax errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra `[` before the second condition in the `elif` branch.

```
elif [[ $CURRENT_OS =~ "CYGWIN" || [ $CURRENT_OS =~ "MSYS" ]]; then
                                   ^ -- Remove this
```

Comment: "before the second condition"

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Steven's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33457342/45375):

**You MUST use `[[ ... ]]` rather than `[ ... ]` to use  Bash's regex-matching operator, `=~`**:

```
[ foo =~ o ] # !! FAILS, due to use of [ ... ]: "[: =~: binary operator expected"

[[ foo =~ o ]] # OK - [[ ... ]] required
```

---

Using idiomatic Bash, you get the following conditionals:

```
if [[ $CURRENT_OS == 'Darwin' ]]; then
    echo "Running OSX"
elif [[ $CURRENT_OS =~ 'CYGWIN' || $CURRENT_OS =~ 'MSYS' ]]; then
    echo "$CURRENT_OS"
fi
```